# Can't edit environment variables on Win 10 Pro from start menu - apps won't launch - java no longer correct version

Tags: windows-10, java, environment-variables

Little lost on what happened here.

Having an issue with Windows overall at the moment, pretty sure an upgrade happened (though not confirmed) and it's after doing something to the machine. I started my investigation when looking to run a java program from my D: drive, which then said it couldn't find the `javaw.exe`.

I went to env variables to check why and I suddenly didn't have access to them which has never been the case before. I can access them from control panel and when I do I'm more confused again, I see the only java var I can see is this one

[image]

which has something called `%JAVA_HOME%` in it, which does not exist in my env variables. When I echo it, it just echos itself like it doesn't exist.

[image]

Then when trying to access something on the `cmd` like `java -v` I get an inaccessibility issue. Checking on it, it looks like the 'Java' folder doesn't exist at this location so I'm not sure what or why it was pointing at this folder.

[image: this folrder doesn't exist]

I eventually found the `javaw.exe` file in this path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

Then I tried adding it to the PATH variable to see if that would help fix this but now I've come across another issue. It's saying the environment variable is too long even when I open it up and only press OK then afterwards

[image]

I noticed when here the Oracle path is here already though so no need to add but I'm just confused overall here. Another symptom of what ever is happening on the machine is I got logged out of every application I use on all browsers, ones I use for work (Chrome), Personal (Brave) and gaming (Brave but another profile). Not sure what caused that either but happened about the same time.

Another symptom is my quick access bookmarks are constantly disappearing even when I just save them it's like they can't live beyond the one session I create them in. Possible these are not connected but they all happened around the same time so feel like they are.

Any one got any ideas what I should do here? I'm not sure what avenue to start chasing down first but maybe someone has ideas? I put at bottom other SE links/topics I've looked at to see for similar issues but they're not quite similar to what i have and didnt solve my issue anyway.

1. can't update env variables from start menu (new behaviour) but can from control panel
2. <s>can't update PATH cause it's 'too long'</s>
3. lost all currently logged in sessions on every browser on the machine
4. can't hold quick access folders in windows explorer they get deleted constantly
5. edit:  <s>to add couldn't use java however that was resolved by uninstalling TWICE, didn't work the first time but an uninstall, reinstall, uninstall restart fixed the java issue</s>

I checked the last updated history to see if that was it but it was a failure whatever it was however it was dated for the year 2030 not sure if that's a good sign or if that was the culprit for the issue

[image]

Other SE topics:

- [Editing System Environment Variables is allowed only when opened through Control Panel](https://superuser.com/questions/1360611/editing-system-environment-variables-is-allowed-only-when-opened-through-control)
- [Can't launch apps from windows 10 start menu search results](https://superuser.com/questions/1070952/cant-launch-apps-from-windows-10-start-menu-search-results)
- [I am admin, but I cannot edit system variables (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1467734/i-am-admin-but-i-cannot-edit-system-variables-windows-10)
- [Windows 10 Home Edition Environment Variables](https://superuser.com/questions/1481153/windows-10-home-edition-environment-variables)

edit: took apart the PATH variable and removed some things I don't need in it to bring the length down but all other issues are still present, so it wasn't that. I feel like a reinstall might be on the cards but I don't know what the root issue is in that case and it may happen again.

Comment: A basic thing to check: create another user and login with that. Does that have the same problems? If not, I'd guess your user profile is corrupt.

Comment: ive never had this issue before so didnt know how to fix but I created another profile, signed in, halfway through testing while logged in it changed my new account session to my old account then when I logged out and back into the main account everything worked again. Now I have quick access working, i can edit env variables too! not sure how the og profile got repaired but thank you for that tip, submit as answer and ill mark as correct!

Comment: Nah mate - it was testing, not offered as solution :-) Do feel free to answer it yourself, you're the only one who can describe what exactly happened. Maybe someone In The Know can decipher the incident :-) The reason I suggested it is just as I said - basic testing. My profile's corrupt once or twice causing all kinds of funky behavior, and I've never found a way to repair it so I've just gone and created a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the initial solution offered by peregrino69 I created another profile on my machine. There was still an odd behaviour here when I logged in with the new profile, mid-way through it changed my active session from the new user to the old user. Not sure what happened or why but then I logged out again and when I logged in my main profile was repaired (if that was indeed the issue). I can now store quick links again and edit env vars from the windows menu screen.

Thanks Peregrino for putting me on the right track

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you but this make ZERO sense.  Windows doesn't just switch active profiles on it's own.  Did you reboot after the updates?  I might have missed that in the post but that is what it is looking like to me.

Comment: yes this is pretty wild and i have no idea how it happened but i saw it with my eyes. I created the new profile with a new email account. Signed in with the profile. tried the few things above that werent working, then when I looked to sign out it changed my profile from the default grey person icon to my normal icon from my profile. I signed out of that profile then signed in again and my profile was working as normal.